# Lefschetz number of a reflection

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fixed-point-theorems

We consider the genus two orientable surface $\Sigma_2$ and the map $r$ which is reflection along a plane cutting $\Sigma_2$ into two punctured tori. I am trying to read off the Lefschetz number of $r$. Well, what $r$ does on first homology is clear: We have four generators (two 'meridians' and two 'longitudes') and none of these is fixed by $r$. So the trace of $H_1(r)$ is zero. How do I quickly calculate $\operatorname{tr}(H_1(r))$ and $\operatorname{tr}(H_2(r))$?

My notes argue like this:

> Clearly, $r$ has trace zero in degree $0$. For degree $2$ we use $H_2(\Sigma_2)\cong H_2(\Sigma_2,\Sigma_2\setminus\{x\})$ for some point $x$ in the intersection of the reflecting plane and $\Sigma_2$. Then the reflection $r$ changes the sign of the fundamental class in $H_2(\Sigma_2,\Sigma_2\setminus\{x\})\cong H_2(S^2,S^2\setminus\{x\})$ and we have $\operatorname{tr}(H_2(r))=-1.$

Why is $H_2(\Sigma_2)\cong H_2(\Sigma_2,\Sigma_2\setminus\{x\})$ true? The punctured genus two surface $\Sigma_2\setminus\{x\}$ is homotopy equivalent to the wedge of four circles. So the map $H_2(\Sigma_2)\rightarrow H_2(\Sigma_2,\Sigma_2\setminus\{x\})$ is injective but not surjective? Also how do you see that $r$ changes the sign of the fundamental class?

---

A quick way to see that $r$ has Lefschetz number zero is to note that the subspace of fixed points is a circle, which has Euler characteristic zero. As $r$ is (homotopic) to a simplicial homeomorphism this Euler characteristic is equal to the Lefschetz number.

Comment: Are you thinking carefully about the relative homology? This is the usual local orientation construction on manifolds. Think about excision.

Comment: @TedShifrin Excision tells me $H_2(\Sigma_2,\Sigma_2\setminus x)\cong H_2(int(D^2), int(D^2)- 0)$ and this is isomorphic to $H_1(S^1)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ by the LES of a pair, so there is an iso $H_2(\Sigma_2)\cong H_2(\Sigma_2,\Sigma_2\setminus\{x\})$. This does not show that the canonical map $H_2(\Sigma_2)\rightarrow H_2(\Sigma_2,\Sigma_2\setminus\{x\})$ is an iso, though?

Comment: But it is. This is the restriction of the global orientation class to the local orientation class at $x$. Have you studied orientations and Poincaré duality?

Comment: @TedShifrin At this point of the lecture we hadn't. But I see, $\Sigma_2$ is compact, connected and orientable (top homology is $\mathbb{Z}$), so there exists a global orientation class which restricts to a given choice of local orientation. And the claim that the trace of $H_2(r)$ is zero is then precisely the claim that $r$ is orientation-reversing. I can see the latter intuitively by thinking of an outer-pointing vector field being turned into an inner-pointing one (or left-handed coordinates to right-handed). But how to make this precise (i.e. show that $H_2(r)$ is multiplication by $-1$)?

Comment: @TedShifrin And a stupid question: How do I see that $H_0(r)$ is the identity?

Comment: Local degree computations are non-trivial in algebraic topology unless you have some basic lemmas relating things to linear algebra or differential topology.  I cannot know what your course has done, and you should talk with your professor about this. Regarding the latter question, $H_0(f)$ is always the identity when you have a map $f$ on a path-connected space. Why?

Comment: @TedShifrin Any two points $x,y$ of a path-connected space $X$ are homologous in $H_0(X)$. The boundary of a path from $x$ to $y$ is $y-x$. (Here I identify the point $x$ with the singular $0$-simplex $\Delta^0 \rightarrow X, 1\mapsto x$ and a path with a singular $1$-simplex, using $\Delta^1\cong [0,1]$). So for any $x\in X$, $x$ and $f(x)$ are equal in $H_0(X)$ and $H_0(f)$ is the identity. Thanks for your help!